# Bootstrap switch tabs with link in content not highlighting active tab

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to link to another tab within the content of a tab. The link switches tabs fine, but the old tab is still highlighted as active. How can I do this properly?

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">This link opens Menu 1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: Click on Menu 3, then the 'Menu 1' link in the content:
https://jsfiddle.net/sua8fmpm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove 'active' class from 'Tab 3' and add it to 'Tab 1' when you click on your link.

You can do it on click in your own code (e.g. jQuery) or using bootstrap tab('show') - more info [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs), it says "selects the given tab and shows its associated content. Any other tab that was previously selected becomes unselected and its associated content is hidden."

Something like this

```
$("#activate-tab-1").click(function(){
    $("#tab-1").tab('show');
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/0nqx1fyv/1/

Comment: Ok, thanks... I was hoping there was a non-jQuery method... but this will do.

Comment: I believe their default behavior doesn't work in this case and doesn't remove/add active class properly because  tab.js expects 'data-toggle' element to be located in the nav-tabs section or something. That's why you have to do it yourself